# slideup panel onclicklistner not working

Tags: android

i am using

> com.sothree.slidinguppanel

its working fine but on click listener is not working below is my code

```
slidingLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
slidingLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //my code
            }
        }
    });
```

so its never going to the my code part i mean its not hitting the on click listener. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's already handled in the Library:

```
    /**
 * Set the draggable view portion. Use to null, to allow the whole panel to
 * be draggable
 * 
 * @param dragView
 *            A view that will be used to drag the panel.
 */
public void setDragView(View dragView) {
    if (mDragView != null) {
        mDragView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    mDragView = dragView;
    if (mDragView != null) {
        mDragView.setClickable(true);
        mDragView.setFocusable(false);
        mDragView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        mDragView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!isEnabled() || !isTouchEnabled())
                    return;
                if (mSlideState != PanelState.EXPANDED && mSlideState != PanelState.ANCHORED) {
                    if (mAnchorPoint < 1.0f) {
                        setPanelState(PanelState.ANCHORED);
                    } else {
                        setPanelState(PanelState.EXPANDED);
                    }
                } else {
                    setPanelState(PanelState.COLLAPSED);
                }
            }
        });
        ;
    }
}
```